# argument type ... could not be detected

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have defined a model (I know, I should be using namespaces but this leads me to other problems, so I decided to leave it for now):

```
class Tx_SimpleOrders_Domain_Model_File extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    ...
}
```

and the controller has two methods for a plugin. The first is to show the form and the second to save the form data to persistance layer. Nothing wild.

```
class Tx_SimpleOrders_Controller_FileController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    public function showAction() {

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump( class_exists('Tx_SimpleOrders_Domain_Model_File') );
        echo "</pre>";

    }



    /**
     * Creates a new file
     *
     * @param Tx_SimpleOrders_Domain_Model_File $newFile A fresh File object which has not yet been persisted
     * @return void
     */
    public function createAction(Tx_SimpleOrders_Domain_Model_File $newFile) {

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_POST["tx_simpleorders_upload"]["newFile"]);
        echo "</pre>";

    }


}
```

The `show` action is correctly invoked. I used that - as you can see - to dump `class_exists('Tx_SimpleOrders_Domain_Model_File')` and it returns `true`. So the model exists.

I always get the error, when I submit the form

```
The argument type for parameter $newFile of method Tx_SimpleOrders_Controller_FileController->createAction() could not be detected.
```

According to the docs, I get this exception, if I don't specify the class of the parameter (as written here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/efs/ExtExtensionFromScratch/Target7ASimpleCrudApplicationTheFePlugins/TheSubmitForm/Index.html).

But I did.

So what's the problem here?

Here is the Fluid "code" of the view:

```
{namespace so=Tx_SimpleOrders_ViewHelpers}

<f:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" controller="File" action="create" name="newFile" object="{newFile}">

  <f:form.textfield property="identifier" /><br />
  <f:form.textarea property="description" rows="3" cols="40" /><br />
  <!--<f:form.upload property="image" /><br />-->
  <f:form.submit class="submit" value="Hochladen" />

</f:form>
```

Comment: have you cleared all caches, especially system cache? the info about arguments is heavily cached

Comment: What TYPO3 version are you using?